# behavior and essential structure of bash argument list

Tags: arrays, bash, arguments, printf

The sample code below demonstrates that the arglist / arguments can be inspected easily with a one-line printf command, whereas an array created from the arguments cannot be inspected with the same command. And it reminds us that the "variable" approach loses the distinction between individual arguments, if any argument happens to contain whitespace.

Is there a way to copy the arglist of a script to a new object which can be examined with this one-line printf command?

Is the argument list of a script identical in its structure and behavior to any object (analogous to an array, a variable, etc.) that one can create in a bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Only for demonstration purposes, override all arguments. 
set -- 'The dog ate the "mouse" ' but the cat?
# Create an array from script arguments.
declare -a argarray=( "$@" )
# Create a variable from script arguments.
argvariable="$@"

# Various ways of trying to inspect script arguments.
printf 'arguments:%s\n' "$@"
declare -p @
printf 'arguments, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in "${@}"
do
    countargs=$(printf '%s\n' "1+$countargs" | bc)
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done
printf '\n'

# Various ways of trying to inspect argarray.
printf 'argarray:%s\n' "$argarray"
declare -p argarray
printf 'argarray, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in "${argarray[@]}"
do
    countargs=$(printf '%s\n' "1+$countargs" | bc)
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done
printf '\n'


# Various ways of trying to inspect argvariable.
printf '\n'
printf 'argvariable:%s\n' "$argvariable"
declare -p argvariable 
printf 'argvariable in curly brackets, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in "${argvariable[@]}"
do
    countargs=$(printf '%s\n' "1+$countargs" | bc)
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done

printf 'argvariable not bracketed, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in $argvariable
do
    countargs=$(printf '%s\n' "1+$countargs" | bc)
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done
```

Comment: why not just `countargs=$#` ? Or even like `countargs=$(printf "%.0s." "$@" | wc -c)`? Calling `printf "%s" 1+1 | bc` is like overkill, even bash arithmetic expansion `((countargs++))` would be enough.

Comment: As soon as you convert the array to a string, you lose the structure and I don't think there's any way to get it back.

Comment: Just keep it in an array.

Comment: Arrays exist precisely *because* `argvariable="$@"` fails to preserve the distinction between word-separating spaces word-internal spaces.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the argument list of a script identical in its structure and behavior to any object (analogous to an array, a variable, etc.) that one can create in a bash script?

Yes, and no. There are similarities, mostly to an array. Let's try to create a list and compare arguments with an array `arr`:

- get argument count: `$#` vs `${#arr[@]}`
- access ex. 3rd argument/element: `$3` vs `${arr[3]}`
- access n-th argument/element: `${@:$n:1}` vs `${arr[$n]}`. But array slicing will work on arrays too: `${arr[@]:$n:1}`.
- set nth argument: Buh, you would have to do `set -- ${@:1:$((n-1))} newvalue ${@:$((n+1))}` vs `arr[$n]=newvalue`
- shifting right: `shift` or, well,  `set -- "${@:2}"` vs `arr=("${arr[@]:1}")`
- argument are always continuous `$0` `$1` `$2`, while you can `arr=(); arr[10]=value; arr[100]=value`.
- getting indices: something along `$(seq $#)` vs `${!arr[@]}`
- get properly escaped: `"$@"` vs `"${arr[@]}"`
- get as a single string: `"$*"` vs `"${arr[*]}"`

To summarize:

- Arguments in scripts are to be accessed using `$@` and `$<number>`.
- You can operate on `$@` a lot like on arrays, but you can't easily assign and/or remove elements.
- There is also the special `shift` command, that shifts the arguments.
- The "special parameters" `$@` `$*` `$#` and `$<number>` and [`shift`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/shift.html) and [`set`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/set.html) commands are specified by [POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14). Bash arrays are available only on bash.

To your script:

- `argvariable="$@"` expands `$@` and joins it using `IFS`. So you'll end with a single string. This is equal to `argvariable="$*"`. So the escaping of arguments is lost.
- `countargs="0"
  for x in "${@}"
  do
  countargs=$(printf '%s\n' "1+$countargs" | bc)
  printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
  done` this can be just simplified to counting ex. newlines from `print %.0s` output: `countargs=$(printf "%.0s\n" "$@" | wc -l)`. Alternatively, you could go with a simple help function: `cntarg() { echo "$#"; }; countargs=$(cntarg "$@")`. Doing `$(printf '%s\n' "1+$countargs" | bc)` is an overkill - shell supports `expr`  command and bash supports arithmetic expansion `$((...))`. You can just `countargs=$((countargs+1))` or even `((countargs++))` to increment a variable.
- `"${argvariable[@]}"` - `argvariable` is not an array. Doing `"${argvariable[@]}"` is equal to `"$argvariable"`.

> Is there a way to copy the arglist of a script to a new object which can be examined with this one-line printf command?

Save the list to an array, like you do in `declare -a argarray=` command.

```
argarray=("$@")
```

You can then access and operate on `argarray` a lot like on `$@`.

Comment: Correction: bash arrays are zero-indexed (at least by default), so the third element will be `${arr[2]}` and the `n`-th will be `${arr[n-1]}`. Also, there's a simpler way to get the `n`-th argument: `${!n}`.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to "Is there a way to copy the arglist of a script to a new object which can be examined with this one-line printf command?":

after

```
set -- 'The dog ate the "mouse" ' but the cat\?
```

the code

```
argarray=( "$@" )
printf 'arguments:%s\n' "${argarray[@]}"
```

produces exactly the same output as

```
printf 'arguments:%s\n' "$@"
```

---

Regarding "Is the argument list of a script identical in its structure and behavior to any object (analogous to an array, a variable, etc.) that one can create in a bash script?", the closest "object" to the argument list (*positional parameters*) is the array.  Arrays are considerably more powerful though.  For example, array elements can be added, set, or removed individually; and arrays can be sparse.  See [Positional Parameters (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters) and [Arrays (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).

---

Note that a counted list of array elements can be printed with:

```
arg_idx=0
for arg in "${argarray[@]}" ; do
    printf "%d: '%s'\\n" $((++arg_idx)) "$arg"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to

> Is there a way to copy the arglist of a script to a new object which can be examined with this one-line printf command?

is unequivocally "Yes. Use an array, but do it right." The most important shortcoming in my sample code was the following

```
printf 'argarray:%s\n' "$argarray"
```

which is now corrected below. Thus it makes sense to routinely create `argarray` at the start of a script. Then the arguments themselves are preserved for later reference.

Note that with an array, one additional way to inspect the elements, **not** available with the arguments themselves, is `declare -p argarray`.

Smaller shortcomings, now corrected thanks to responses, were

1. The "overkill" method for incrementing countargs
2. My imprecise term "variable" when "string" would have been clearer
3. Not making it clear that I wanted not only to know the total number of arguments but to display their numeric indices.

I keep the "string" treatment at the bottom this sample code, as a reminder that turning the arguments into a string is a bad idea.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Only for demonstration purposes, override all arguments. 
set -- 'The dog ate the "mouse" ' but the cat?
# Create an array from script arguments.
declare -a argarray=( "$@" )
# Create a variable from script arguments.
argstring="$@"

# Various ways of trying to inspect script arguments.
printf 'arguments, printf:%s\n' "$@"
declare -p @
printf 'arguments indexed, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in "${@}"
do
    countargs=$((countargs+1));
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done
printf '\n'

# Various ways of trying to inspect argarray.
printf 'argarray, printf:%s\n' "${argarray[@]}"
declare -p argarray
printf 'argarray indexed, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in "${argarray[@]}"
do
    countargs=$((countargs+1));
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done
printf '\n'

# Various ways of trying to inspect argstring.
printf 'argstring, printf:%s\n' "$argstring"
declare -p argstring
printf 'argstring indexed, curly brackets, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in "${argstring[@]}"
do
    countargs=$((countargs+1));
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done
printf 'argstring indexed, not bracketed, loop:\n'
countargs="0"
for x in $argstring
do
    countargs=$((countargs+1));
    printf '%s\n' "$countargs: '$x'"
done
printf '\n'
```

Result:

```
> bash-example.sh
arguments, printf:The dog ate the "mouse" 
arguments, printf:but
arguments, printf:the
arguments, printf:cat?
/Users/BNW/u/kh/bin/bash-example.sh: line 11: declare: @: not found
arguments indexed, loop:
1: 'The dog ate the "mouse" '
2: 'but'
3: 'the'
4: 'cat?'

argarray, printf:The dog ate the "mouse" 
argarray, printf:but
argarray, printf:the
argarray, printf:cat?
declare -a argarray='([0]="The dog ate the \"mouse\" " [1]="but" [2]="the" [3]="cat?")'
argarray indexed, loop:
1: 'The dog ate the "mouse" '
2: 'but'
3: 'the'
4: 'cat?'

argstring, printf:The dog ate the "mouse"  but the cat?
declare -- argstring="The dog ate the \"mouse\"  but the cat?"
argstring indexed, curly brackets, loop:
1: 'The dog ate the "mouse"  but the cat?'
argstring indexed, not bracketed, loop:
1: 'The'
2: 'dog'
3: 'ate'
4: 'the'
5: '"mouse"'
6: 'but'
7: 'the'
8: 'cat?'
```